# Matrix input result (Python)

Tags: python, list, input, matrix

I have this code wrote in python,used to input a matrix:

```
def gestionmatrice():       

    print("Entrez la matrice,séparé par des espaces pour chaques colonnes")
    print("une rangée par ligne,et faites un ligne vide pour terminer")
    matrix = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if not line: break
        values = line.split()
        row = [int(value) for value in values]
        matrix.append(row)

    print(matrix)
```

The user input the matrix by entering all desired `int` value per row separated by a space,then press enter to confirm the row and `input` the next one. To finish, user have to `input` a blank row and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. At the end,I want to see the matrix by printing it; the problem is that it doesn't work correctly; if for example the user input `1 2 3` and then `4 5 6` on the next row, the `print(matrix)` will result as:`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.It would be supposed to `print` `1 2 3
                  4 5 6` so something doesn't work.What has to be modified? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make clear in the question body what you would expect the output to be? I tried to salvage it in my edit but I couldn't make it out.

Comment: actually I would like the output to display 1 2 3 and on the row under,4 5 6 aligned with the 1 2 3.

Comment: What happens when there's a `10`? Do you want everything to be aligned?

Comment: In a perfect world,yes,but its also okay like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure quite why you want it to be like that, but you could do something like:

Instead of `print(matrix)`, do:

```
>>> print(*(' '.join(map(str, sub)) for sub in matrix), sep='\n')
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

That is the quick fix.

Comment: @HaiVu Realised that pretty much as you posted, edited and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can print out a matrix in Python like this:

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix]))
```

Here's a get matrix function:

```
def get_matrix():
    matrix = []
    line = input()
    while line:
        matrix.append(map(int, line.split()))
        line = input()
    return matrix
```

Demo:

```
>>> matrix = get_matrix()
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

>>> print_matrix(matrix)
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

is the default printing of a matrix (in many language, not only python).

To achieve what you want you have to do something like

```
import sys
for i in xrange(2):
    for j in xrange(3):
        sys.stdout.write(str(matrix[i,j] + " "))
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Comment: oh really? I thought I was wrong since I thought [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] was just like 2 list in a big list,and not a matrix.So its still a matrix,and its just normal that it result a display like this [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]? Thanks

Comment: @Jon_Computer That's "a" way to represent matrices, but by itself python will never print a matrix like you originally wanted to.